Two-step lookup in Excel
Having a known Y value and a Known (x,y) value, find Y value in a table.
Essentially, I have a table with (x) values along A:A and (y) values along 1:1 with the corresponding (x,y) values within the table.
I would like Excel to find the (y) value in the 1:1 row from user-inputted (x) and (x,y) values.
For example:
(x,y) table the user would input "33" and "2.01" and we are looking for Excel to output "4"
Ive tried a few permutations of using VLOOKUP and MATCH, but Excel is throwing "Value Not Available" errors. I'm fairly certain that I'm close to a correct usage, but cant quite visualize the answer to make it all fit together and can't find the correct way to ask the question to properly search for the answer.

Without more info on your data, this is not reproducable. Also posting you've tried without your actual try, isn't helping us help you.

I've provided an example table. I'm looking for what process of excel formulas would be used to accomplish this task, so the specific data is somewhat irrelevant. I have a feeling I may need to do something like a "inverse" HLOOKUP nested inside of a VLOOKUP. Or just remove the nesting, run an "inverse" HLOOKUP where instead of looking for the "value in the top row of a table" excel is looking for the "value in the column from a row you specify" - essentially inverting the lookup and return portions of the HLOOKUP function

=XLOOKUP(B10,XLOOKUP(B9,B2:B7,C2:H7),C1:H1) where x is in B9 and y in B10 ? =INDEX(C1:F1,MATCH(B10,INDEX(C2:F7,MATCH(B9,B2:B7,0),),0))

XLOOKUP returns a range, which can be re-used. Same with INDEX/MATCH

If you have Excel 2021 or later, you could use LET to make the parts easy to follow: =LET(     x_input, 33,     xy_input, 2.01,     table, A1:G8,     x_values, INDEX(table, , 1),     y_values, INDEX(table, 1, ),     xys_for_x, XLOOKUP(x_input, x_values, table),     XLOOKUP(xy_input, xys_for_x, y_values) )

Here/below refer.  Some original yet concise/parsimonious methods here.
Unique in table
=SUM(C2:H2*(C3:H9=2.01))



Quickest/shortest function (challenge open to anyone for shorter!)
Only 2 inputs (table/header + 2.01; 33 redundant info on this
premise/basis)
Not w/ flaws: requires inputs within sum to be value-based; no errors allowed


Unique in row for [33]
Method 1 - boring
=INDEX(C2:H2,,MATCH(2.01,INDEX(C3:H9,MATCH(33,B3:B9,0),0)))



Boring, yet robust - will work for non-value/text within table.

Method 2 - special
=SUM(C2:H2*(C3:H9=2.01)*(B3:B9=33))



Not unique in table
Now we're getting into the nitty-gritty. Assuming 2.01 not unique (in row for [33] or in other rows.
This prevents us from using the sum function.  Will need to join multiple values 1-6 for where 2.01 exists in row for [33].
=LET(x_,INDEX(C13:H19,MATCH(33,B3:B9,0),0),TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(C2:H2,--(x_=2.01))))


̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿

